# SignalR Core and ASP.NET Core 2.x: getting 404 every 5 seconds on negotiate

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm using SignalR Core and ASP.NET Core 2.x.

Client version: 1.0.3
Server version: 1.0.3.18207
Running on Azure App Service.

I'm getting tons of 404 errors, every 5 seconds for each user that is logged in. This is the error:

/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=...

I cannot reproduce this error in my dev enviroment, it only happens when I deploy it to Azure App Service. In my dev environment I also tried it with bundles (setting the environment to Production) but the issue doesn't happen).

Something important to point out: the notifications work both in DEV and PROD environment. I don't see any functional issues, just this error that is crashing the system when more users are logged in. Just an observation, even with one user logged in you can see the error.

**EDIT**: This error happens every 5 seconds. I haven't change any default configuration like KeepAlive.

[image]

StartUp.ConfigureServices:

```
            // SignalR
            services
                .AddSignalR()
                .AddJsonProtocol(options =>
                {
                    options.PayloadSerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
                });
```

StartUp.Configure:

```
            app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<MessageHub>("/MessageHub");
            });
```

Messages are working fine but I still get the 400 error every 5 seconds as described above.

Azure App Service App Settings:

[image]

Comment: ?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=... means you're not using ASP.NET Core SignalR. Are you sure you're using the right client?

Comment: Yes, I'm using ASP.NET Core SignalR JavaScript Client 1.0.3. At server side I have Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR (1.0.3). I added a screenshot to the question. I also added some extra information like the fact that the error hapens every 5 seconds.

Comment: OK well that URL is probably some incorrect paste. A 404 usually means sticky sessions aren't enabled.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. I'm using Azure App Services with one instance and ARR Affinity cookies are enabled. I edited my question adding information about Azure App Service settings and ASP.NET Core StartUp configuration.

Comment: Can you follow this guide https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/wiki/Diagnostics-Guide and provide more information?

Comment: I will try to prepare all the information you requested. It might take me a few days as I have just deployed the main application of the company in PROD using ASP.NET Core 2 and there's a lot to do yet :)

Comment: Feels like cookies aren't being round tripped by your browser. Getting the HAR file would be useful here.

Comment: Are you using chrome?

Comment: I'm using Chrome but I'm not blocking 3rd party cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using chrome and do you have 3rd party cookies disabled?

[image: Disabled cokies]

Comment: I'm using Chrome but I'm not blocking 3rd party cookies.

Comment: Can you verify that the ARR Affinity cookie gets set in the negotiate response? Were you ever able to get the HAR file from the client

Comment: Yes, ARR Affinity cookie is set. I cannot get the HAR file because I cannot reproduce the issue myself. I added [Authorize] to the Hub and it seems now I'm not getting 404s anymore, does it make any sense?